# read cookie in javascript , made by asp.net c#code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies

I've made a cookie using **asp.net C# code** and I want to retrieve its value  in **javascript**

Here's my **C# code**:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("doc1count");
cookie.Value = "hellonitesh";
```

I am using this **code**:

```
var cookie = '@HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["doc1count"].Value';
alert(cookie);
```

but its giving me garbage value.

Answer (score 4):

Try to separate client and server side
Add cookies to responce on server:

```
HttpCookie myCookie= new HttpCookie("doc1count");
myCookie.Value = "hellonitesh";
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

And retrieve it in javascript (You can find more examples
[here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp))

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
var myCookie = getCookie("doc1count")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) plugin to manage cookie at client end. Apart from this, I can see in your C# code you are not posting the cookie variable. So you should do like following -
`HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookie_name","cookie_value"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just access it through ASP.NET variable by adding in the inline code I have right here. That's if you wanna be fairly simple about it, you can check if it contains anything with an if statement before assigning it I believe.

```
 var cookie = '<%= Request.Cookies["cookieID"].ToString() %>';
 alert(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var cookie = '@Request.Cookies["culture"].Value';
```